# Please help to identify this vine

Tags: identification, vines, creepers

[image: woody light red-brown stem with dark waxy leaves]

This vine grows on the ground in our front yard, creeping out from under the hedgerow. We've always just mowed it. But, I am curious as to what it is. Apparently planted by previous owners. I almost ID'd it as a Hoya but not sure the stick like stem qualifies. The stem reminds me of honeysuckle without the fuzz. Seems it might make a wonderful topiary wrap.

Comment: Midge, welcome! Please note that this is an international site, so some info about your location might help - for example, I have honeysuckle in my garden, but hoya would never survive our winter where I live... Just [edit] your post. Oh, and let me recommend taking the [tour] and visiting our [help] for more info on how this site works.

Comment: Does it flower? If so, can you describe them if you don't have a photo.

Comment: Does it flower is a big question.  It should at least be displaying buds this time of year.  I used to have a 'twin flower' vine thing that I didn't even know the botanical name...that looked like this.  White flowers that were twins.  Gorgeous and not liking too much cold.  How about last year?  Did you ever see the flowers?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=twin+flower+vine&rlz=1C1QJDB_en&espv=2&biw=1067&bih=533&tbm=isch&imgil=_1fxCoaAIoyrUM%253A%253BboNjsGSI4B6IpM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fsimplyorcas.com%25252Ftag%25252Ftwinflower%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=_1fxCoaAIoyrUM%253A%252CboNjsGSI4B6IpM%252C_&usg=__DUJRbh2mQ4PHeKgHxNfjla1STJ0%3D&ved=0ahUKEwi8-4v6rK3MAhVGw2MKHVGtDv4QyjcIJw&ei=gesfV_y2B8aGjwPR2rrwDw#imgrc=R89puJXeZvXcXM%3A

Comment: This vine has never flowered in my yard here in Niceville, FL, USA. Hardiness Zone 8b

Comment: Stormy, that's a close match but this vine comes to a definite point whereas your example has a rounded end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nearby car dealership has this as a ground cover in several areas. The lawn maintenance tech says it is jasmine. Lucky me! Maybe it will flower if we stop mowing it. Or, as my research shows, it could be a non-flowering faux jasmine, which still makes an awesome ground cover.